# constructor and this pointer

Tags: php, constructor, this-pointer

The question is: after declaration "private $json" should i use in constructor $json or $this->json ?

```
class Controller{
private $json;
 private $data;
  function __construct(){
  $json=json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['json']));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You **must** use `$this->` here, otherwise you are not assigning it to the instance but just creating a local variable in the constructor that will be gone after the constructor has run. There is no optional `$this` in php, you must always specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it either way, but after you assign it to `$this->json`, I'd recommend continuing to use that value.

The idea is that, if your constructor has other operations or method calls, those methods may be written to depend on `$this->json`.

It's my practice to set instance variables early and use them exclusively after they've been set.

Answer (score 0):

Unless $json is a local variable that shouldn't affect $this->json, I'd recommend using $this->json from the time you assign. To clarify:

```
class Controller{
private $json;
 private $data;
  function __construct(){
      $this->json = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['json']));
      echo $this->json;
  }
}
```

Makes more sense than something like:

```
class Controller{
private $json;
 private $data;
  function __construct(){
       $json = json_decode(base64_decode($_POST['json']));
       $this->json = $json;
       echo $json;
  }
}
```

Comment: so $this->json from your example has still private attibute ?